# Как выдать нескольким пользователям права на одну папку?

Tags: linux, centos7

Используется ос centos7, есть 2 юзера Ivanov и Petrov.
В корне есть директория Txt. Иванов должен уметь создавать и сохранять без удаления, а Петров чтение  и запуск в этой папке.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, с помощью только механизма разделения прав файловой системы — невозможно. Создание и удаление файлов — это один и тот же permission, а именно — запись в каталог.

Comment: А это задание у нас такое,  препод сказал - "возможно, думайте"

Comment: Препод — штука такая... Повторите для себя его формулировку и найдите в ней потенциальные лазейки, через которые он потом из своего задания выкрутится :)

Comment: А вообще, посмотрите на SELinux. Неспроста там, возможно, указана именно семёрка.

Comment: Поместить их в одну группу, задать права папке для данной группы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
setfacl -m u:Ivanov:rwx /test
setfacl -m u:Petrov:rx /test
```

> Первый пользователь Ivanov будет иметь полный доступ,
>
> а второй пользователь Petrov будет иметь только права на чтение и
>   выполнение.

+
Поставить Атрибуты на папку

```
chattr +i /test
chattr -i /test   (Убрать Атрибуты)
```

Просмотр Атрибутов (Запрет от дурака)

```
lsattr test/
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

DIR 001 (Установлен атрибут +i Удалить содержимое не получится)